# Как записи Firebase вывести в обратном порядке?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Такой код
`myRef.orderByChild("count").startAt(0).endAt(999)`
выводит записи в хронологическом порядке. А как их вывести в обратном от большего к меньшему?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase всегда отдает результаты запроса по возрастанию. Этот [вопрос](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/310) уже год назад был озвучен, но так и не был решен. Поэтому только обходные пути решения с помощью адаптера.

```
@override
public User getItem(int position) {
   return super.getItem(getItemCount() - 1 - position);
}
```

Или с помощью коллекций, когда данные получены:

```
Collections.sort(mylist, new Comparator<InfoClass>() {
@Override
public int compare(InfoClass infoClass1, InfoClass infoClass2) {
     return  //сравнение значений из класса
    }
});
Collections.reverse(mylist);
```